# Show that $\frac{1}{1+f(n)} = 1 +\mathcal{O}(g(n))$ for $f(n) = \mathcal{O}(g(n)), g(n) = \mathcal{o}(1)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, combinatorics, asymptotics

> Consider $f,g: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ with $f(n) = \mathcal{O}(g(n))$ and $g(n) = \mathcal{o}(1)$. Show that $$\frac{1}{1+f(n)} = 1 +\mathcal{O}(g(n)).$$

My idea would be that since $$\frac{1}{1+f(n)} -1 = -\frac{f(n)}{1+f(n)} \le 0$$

the claim follows automatically by the positiviy of $g$. Is it really that easy or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frequently when people say $h = O(g)$ for some $h$, $g$ that possibly have signs, they mean that for $x \gg 1$ and some constant $C$, $|h(x)| \leq C |g(x)|$.

I personally don't like this convention, and I try to keep track of signs wherever possible by assuming $g \geq 0$ and $h$ (eventually) doesn't change signs. Then we can write $h = O(g)$ or $h = - O(g)$ as appropriate.

Regardless, this (standard) convention means that showing $\frac{1}{1 + f} - 1 \leq 0$ isn't actually enough to show that it's $O(g)$ (as you've intuited). We need to show that (eventually)

$$
\left | \frac{1}{1+f} - 1 \right | \leq Cg.
$$

Now it turns out this *still* isn't so hard to do directly (using the fact that $f = O(g)$). Indeed,

$$
\left | \frac{1}{1+f} - 1 \right | = 
\left | \frac{-f}{1+f} \right | =
\frac{f}{1+f} \leq 
f = O(g)
$$

So we see $\frac{1}{1+f} = 1 + O(g)$, as requested.

---

I hope this helps ^_^